# Kotlin Retrofit response.body() returned null on arrayList

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, retrofit2

i have setup some API data to display on my Android APP

> ```
> [
>   {"attendanceID":1,"userID":1,"date":"14 Apr","clock_in":"10:11","clock_out":"19:39","noted":"Weekday"},
>   {"attendanceID":2,"userID":1,"date":"15 Apr","clock_in":"23:09","clock_out":"N.A.","noted":"Weekday"},
>   {"attendanceID":3,"userID":1,"date":"16 Apr","clock_in":"19:19 ","clock_out":"19:42 ","noted":"Weekday"}
> ]
> ```

my data model is this

> ```
> data class Attendance (
>     val userID: Int,
>     val date: String?,
>     val clock_in: String?,
>     val clock_out: String?,
>     val noted: String?
>     )
> ```

the interface is this

> ```
> interface INodeJS {
>   @GET("load_attendance")
>   fun loadAttendance(): Call<ArrayList<Attendance>>
> }
> ```

and my code is this

> ```
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
> import android.os.Bundle
> import android.widget.Toast
> import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
> import com.example.absensi.ui.retrofit.INodeJS
> import com.example.absensi.ui.retrofit.RetrofitClient
> import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_detail_absensi.*
> import retrofit2.Call
> import retrofit2.Callback import retrofit2.Response
>
> class DetailAbsensi : AppCompatActivity() {
>
> lateinit var myAPI : INodeJS
> private val attendanceList = ArrayList<Attendance>()
>
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_absensi)
>
>     val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
>     myAPI = retrofit.create(INodeJS::class.java)
>     rvAttendance.setHasFixedSize(true)
>     rvAttendance.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
>
>     myAPI.loadAttendance().enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Attendance>> {
>         override fun onResponse(
>                 call: Call<ArrayList<Attendance>>,
>                 response: Response<ArrayList<Attendance>>
>         ) {
>             attendanceList.addAll(response.body()!!)
>             val adapter = AttendanceAdapter(attendanceList)
>             rvAttendance.adapter = adapter
>         }
>
>         override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Attendance>>, t: Throwable) {
>         }
>
>     })
>
> }
>
> }
> ```

but i always get this error when i open my DetailAbsensi

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

so after some hour checking my code i found that when running code myAPI.loadAttendance().enqueue the response i get when i checking response.body() is all null

> ```
> [
>   Attendance{userID=0,date="Null",clockin="Null",clockout="Null",noted="Noted"},
>   Attendance{userID=0,date="Null",clockin="Null",clockout="Null",noted="Noted"},
>   Attendance{userID=0,date="Null",clockin="Null",clockout="Null",noted="Noted"}
> ]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this on every property of the object

```
data class Attendance (
@SerializedName("userID")
val userID: Int,
@SerializedName("date")
val date: String?,
@SerializedName("clock_in")
val clock_in: String?,
@SerializedName("clock_out")
val clock_out: String?,
@SerializedName("noted")
val noted: String?
)
```

Your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your `activity.xml` file.
In the recyclerView:

```
  app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that you are calling these statements from the "main" thread outside of a delayed asynchronous callback (for example inside the onCreate() method). As soon as I call the same statements from a "delayed" method. In my case a ResultCallback, I get the same message.

In my Fragment, calling the code below from inside a ResultCallback method produces the same message. After moving the code to the onConnected() method within my app, the message was gone...

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
list.setLayoutManager(llm);
list.setAdapter( adapter );
```